# DocuSign Production Issue - Go Live process followed, but doesn't work

Tags: docusignapi

We have shifted our DocuSign integration from Sandbox to Production. All credentials of the sandbox are working. Also, our integration key from staging has been promoted to DocuSign's live production environment.

But when we are using production credentials then we are getting an error.

We are using docusign-esign npm package in our Node project.

This is the code after which error comes:

```
const client = new docuSign.ApiClient({
basePath,
oAuthBasePath,
});
const jwtTokenResult = await client.requestJWTUserToken(integratorKey, userId, scopes, privateKeyFile, expiresIn);
```

After the above line we get this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:443
```

Paths/URLs of Sandbox

```
basePath: 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'
oAuthBasePath: 'account-d.docusign.com'
```

Paths/URLs of Production

```
basePath: 'https://eu.docusign.net/restapi'
oAuthBasePath: 'https://account.docusign.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
client = new docusign.ApiClient();
client.setOAuthBasePath(dsConfig.dsOauthServer.replace('https://', ''));
client.setBasePath(args.basePath);
const jwtTokenResult = await client.requestJWTUserToken(integratorKey, userId, scopes, privateKeyFile, expiresIn);
```

Comment: We've just tried this. We still get the same error as before. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please if can send email to go-live@docusign.com with your integration key, and we will have a look if there is an issue with the account settings

Comment: Thanks, I just did that. Should I share my case number with you?